# NumerFormat doesn't allow me to add ","

Tags: flutter

I want to have currency formatted matching Italian (most of Europe) semantics. To do so I write one number format functionality but it doesn't allow me to add "," as fractional part in value.

```
class CurrencyInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter{
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // TODO: implement formatEditUpdate
    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      print(true);
      return newValue;
    }
    double value = double.parse(newValue.text);
    final formatter = new NumberFormat("#,###.##", "it_IT");
    String newText = formatter.format(value);
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: newText,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the outcome? Do your method alter anything or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CnbPclyulUcGrFHZ7tpCt_CliCWvmw2q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try this final formatter = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "it_IT"); because I have done in my project final formatter = new NumberFormat("##,##,##0.00", "en_US");

Comment: thanks @Parth Patel " final formatter = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "it_IT");" it's working but once i enter the value and if i erase that value then by default it contains "0,00" . how can i remove that.

Comment: Hi Parth Bhanderi I will answer full code below which may helps you. I have used same format as you have used and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dependency pubspec.yaml file.

```
intl: ^0.15.8
```

Following is the Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  NumberFormat currencyFormat = new NumberFormat("#,###.##", "it_IT");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Number Format'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                '${currencyFormat.format(200011.56)}',
              )
            ],
          ),
        ), 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @parthpatel format working perfect but if i'm erase all value from textfield then "0,00" remaining in textfield and i don't want that, i didn't find any solution to remove that "0,00" from my textfields.

Comment: Hi @ParthBhanderi , try to put the condition for blank value in text field. If text input field is blank then don't try to  format the currency else format it